Issue with Unequal Margins on Odd and Even Pages in Springer Nature's LaTeX Template
I downloaded the "Springer Nature’s LaTeX" template from here.
Upon compiling the LaTeX document, I noticed that the margins on odd and even pages are different.
Could you please advise on what modifications I should make to ensure that the margins are the same on both odd and even pages?

You're presumably using the sn-jnl document class because you're required to do so. E.g., you may be planning to submit a piece for publication in one of the Springer-stable journals. If this assumption is valid, why would you want to mess with the formatting-related setup contained in the Springer template file(s)?

It is normal that margins on even/odd pages are different to a) accommodate space for binding and b) to result in consistent spaces on the outer edges and the middle of a double spread page.

the whole point of a journal class is that the publisher chooses the page size and layout and authors should not change this as the format will be the fomat required by the publisher. Having different margins on odd an even pages is quite normal. most classes will have this for twoside documents
